# Signal R multiple Web API requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr

Hi can someone help regarding my issue in SignalR I have created a sample realtime database I'm having a problem when I change some data in the database I get multiple request in the API is this okay? or it has performance issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOTq8.png)
I've got 1278 request from the API and I only change one value from the data in the database.

My Sql code

```
   public IEnumerable<Vehicles> Read(OnChangeEventHandler dependency)
    {
        var list = new List<Vehicles>();

        using (Con)
        {
            Con.Open();
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Cmd.CommandText = _proc.ReadVehicle;

            Cmd.Notification = null;

            var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(Cmd);
            sqlDependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency);


            if (Con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                Con.Open();
            }


            using (var reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        list.Add(new Vehicles
                        {
                            Id = Convert.ToInt16(reader["Id"]),
                            Car = reader["Car"].ToString(),
                            Brand = reader["Brand"].ToString(),
                            Company = reader["Company"].ToString(),
                            Image = reader["Image"].ToString(),
                            LifeTime = Convert.ToInt16(reader["LifeTime"]),
                            Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Price"]),
                            Type = reader["Type"].ToString(),
                            Year = reader["Year"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Here is my API Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var list = this._service.ReadVehicles((e, sqlNotif) =>
        {
            if (sqlNotif.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                var hub = new VehicleHub();
                hub.GetVehicles();
            }

        });

        return Ok(list);
    }
```

My Signal R Hub

```
[HubName("VehicleHub")]
public class VehicleHub : Hub
{

    [HubMethodName("getAllVehicles")]
    public void GetVehicles()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<VehicleHub>();
        context.Clients.All.getAllVehicles();
    }

}
```

My Client Side script

```
     $(function () {

         var vehicles = $.connection.VehicleHub;
         vehicles.client.getAllVehicles = function () {
             getVehicles()

        };

         $.connection.hub.start();
         getVehicles()

    });

    function getVehicles() {

        var tbl = $('#carTable');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:62734/api/vehicle',
            contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                tbl.empty();
                $.each(result, function (key, value) {
                    tbl.append('<tr>' +
                        '<td>' + value.Id + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + value.Car + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + value.Brand + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + value.Type + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>');
                }
                )
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is ok, the reason it displays multiple request is, it using long pooling instead of Web Sockets, looks like in your local testing you haven't enabled web sockets in your IIS Express.

In Web Sockets, one connection is kept open and it both server and client can ping regularly to each other to ensure both are connected.

Long polling works this way, http connection is opened and client waits for an update, if server has any update then it will send an update to client or it will eventually close and allow client to reopen the connection to make sure both are alive. Since server has no way to receive ping from client in Long polling, server closes and client reopens the connection which logically serves as ping to ensure both are connected.

From Windows features, you can install Web Sockets support for IIS Express and these multiple connections will be replaced with Web Sockets and you will not see many requests.